# the height of hover div is increasing

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on Wordpress with Bootstrap responsive theme.

My problem is that I want a hover effect on my image, but when I hover on the image the height of hover div is increasing.

As I said I'm using responsive theme, but when I open it on mobile screen it doesn't response, and the width of the div increased to whole page. I'm using `span3` class for making the image responsive.

Here is my Css for image and hover div:

```
.image{position: relative;}.image img {max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}.hoverimage {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);/* For IE 5.5 - 7*/filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);/* For IE 8*/-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";}
.image:hover .hoverimage { display: block;}.image_text {color:#FFFFFF;margin:60px;}
```

and Here is the code where I'm using the hover div:

```
<li class="span3 image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/270x150" alt="" class="img-polaroid" /><div class="hoverimage img-polaroid"><p class="image_text"><a href="https://globalmanetwork.com/">globalmanetwork.com/</a></p></div>
</li>

<li class="span3 image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/270x150" alt="" class="img-polaroid" /><div class="hoverimage img-polaroid"><p class="image_text"><a href="https://globalmanetwork.com/">globalmanetwork.com/</a></p></div>
</li>
```

Comment: Fiddle for the code appreciated.

Comment: Hum, I do a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNxKp/) to see the case, and the hover div fits nicely in the screen... have you tried to give a 100% max-width to the `<ul>` container?

Comment: @Arkana: thnks for ur jsfiddle. thats what my problem is.as u can seee the hover div is allover the image and i just want it to be over the image.

Comment: @NathanLee:here is te jsfiddle for it:http://jsfiddle.net/aNxKp/

Comment: your **list element** with class `.image` **should restrain your div** but since it has **no width or height** assigned to it it will be stretched to maximum size since list elements are block elements by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### jQuery solution

As @Rakesh say, you can achieve the expected behaviour with jQuery: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aNxKp/1/)**

```
$('div.hoverimage').each(function()
{
    var width = $(this).prev().width();
    $(this).width(width);
});
```

NOTE: In Chrome, this works setting the jQuery onDomReady (in jsFiddle options), I have seen right now...

---

### Pure CSS solution (knowing img dimensions)

Otherwise, if you know previously the width and height of the images (in this case, 270px), you can do something like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aNxKp/3/)**.

In this case I put a `text-align:center` to avoid the fixed margin, and set a `word-wrap:break-word` to prevent the paragraph go outside the container.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: @ManindraSingh If this solution helps you, a upvote (and accept if apply) might be welcome ;)

Comment: @ Arkana:thanks a lot for ur help.its working good now.but it just have one problem now and that is its height as u can see it after removing one <li>.the height of <li> is still bigger than the image.

Comment: @ManindraSingh To fix that simply add `line-height:0;` to your `<li>`elements ;)

Comment: @ Arkana still not working i just gave the <li style="line-height:0;"> i want to mention that the default line height for <li> in bootstrap is 20px;

Comment: @ManindraSingh I don't know how implement this in your bootstrap template, but in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/aNxKp/5/) it works... could you look with firebug or other developer tool if line-height is effectively aplicated?

Comment: @ Arkana : i have checked it through firebug line height is applicted effectively.but i m unable to understand why its not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30985/discussion-between-manindra-singh-and-arkana)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some CSS

Try this;

```
 .image {

        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .image img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
    .hoverimage {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 97%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
        /* For IE 8*/
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
    }
    .image:hover .hoverimage {
        display: inline;
        width:54%;
        /*height:100%; */
    }
    .image_text {
        color:#FFFFFF;
        margin:60px;
    }
```

Let me know is this helpfull?.

Comment: But, with this code, the hover effects only cover 54% of the space... if the viewport is less tan 300px width, only covers 54% of the image, and if the viewport is more than 600px, the cover extends outside the image.

Comment: i think you have to use JavaScript for get dynamic height and width of images. so based on height/width you can set div property.